# How to make a clickable div with a rollover image-link inside of it?

Tags: css, html, rollover

I'm trying to make a clickable div hold my rollover image link inside of it. I already have the rollover image inside of it, but the whole div isn't turning into a clickable link.

**The html looks like this:**

```
 <div class="left1" id="range-logo">
 <div class="left1button"> <a href="#"></a> </div>               
 </div>
```

**My rollover image link is functioning, but the div that's holding that rollover image link isn't turning into a link. I want the whole thing to be a link/clickable.**

What I'm trying to achieve by doing this, is having a clickable div with a background image (#range-logo is giving it the background). I want that background image to change when hovered over. And also, inside of that div, I want an image rollover link.

**Site I'm working on can be found here:**

http://shopmoonfall.bigcartel.com/

**I'm working on the first div underneath the big slider (first girl with sunglasses).**

Comment: the "read our blog" is supposed to have an image inside it too?

Comment: No I already have the rollover image-link inside of it. I just need that whole div into a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I think I unserstand, it's hard to give you exact code with out anything posted but use

```
#range-logo:hover a{
    background-color: #FFF
    //add whatever styles you want on that tag
}
```

**EDIT**
Just use an `a` tag and add `id="range-logo"` to it. `a`'s are `inline-block` by nature so if you want it to behave like a div use `display: block;`. Now you don't need that second `a` tag inside, use a `div` and add a class to it

```
<a class="left1" id="range-logo" href="/products">
    <div class="left1button"> <div class="someName"></div></div>             
</a>
```

**EDIT 2**

you have this script that's targeting an `a` inside of `.left1button`

```
.left1button a {
   display: block;
   width: 158px;
   height: 37px;
   top: 175px;   
   left: 75px;
   background-image: url(http://oi40.tinypic.com/2zfr7h4.jpg);
}
```

So you can do 1 of 2 things, you can use `<div></div>` instead of `<a href="#"></a>` and change the above target to be `.left1button div` or you can remove that whole thing and use something like

```
.someName { //Call this whatever you want
   display: block;
   width: 158px;
   height: 37px;
   top: 175px;   
   left: 75px;
   background-image: url(http://oi40.tinypic.com/2zfr7h4.jpg);
}
```

and then you can use my example above. Whatever you want

Comment: To make the div into a link with a rollover image-link inside of it?

Comment: well you're using `onclick="location.href='/products'`, i guess i dont understand. Can you explain some more?

Comment: That works, I just added that part. But it isn't showing where the location/link goes when you hover over the div, like most hyperlinks do. So I'm trying to either modify that code, or figure out another way, instead of using that onclick idea.

Comment: Thanks for this! Can you do me a favor though and write out how I should have it?

 <div class="left1" id="range-logo" onclick="location.href='/products';" style="cursor: pointer;">
    
<div class="left1button"> <a href="#"></a> </div>             
  </div>

Comment: do you mean write out the css? The HTML is above

Comment: What do I use "someName" for? haha. Sorry, I'm sorta' confused about that part. Like, where would I put the clickable rollover image in that html?

Comment: oh gotcha, yeah updating above

Comment: Man, I still don't really get what you're saying haha. It's hard to explain what I'm trying to accomplish. If you go to http://shopwasteland.com/ and look at their images on their homepage (inside the grid) then you'll get what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: I added the first code you gave me though (EDIT) and the div is clickable now, but the rollover image-link isn't showing up.

Comment: Just a question though, why is it that when I get rid of <div class="someName"></div> the button disappears? Even though .someName isn't even classified in my CSS?

Comment: if you used `left1button div` then the class name is irrelevant because it's targeting any `div` inside of `left1button` and applying those styles

Comment: Okay so your help was fantastic! I got it to work exactly how I want! But now, I'd like the middle div underneath the slider to not show the rollover image-link until the div is hovered. How do I achieve this?

Comment: if I understand you correctly, you dont want the "read more" part to highlight unless you're specifically hovering over it? Just take out that first code I game you `#range-logo:hover a{`

Comment: I never added that in haha. But nah what I'm trying to say is, I don't want the "FOLLOW US ON IG" 'button' to show up unless that div is hovered over.

Comment: ok, where you style that button: `left2button div` change `display: block` to `display: none` and then use `#range-logo:hover .left2button div{ display: inline}`

Comment: try adding a `;` to the end of `inline;`, sorry i left that out, im not sure that's it but it might be

Comment: ok sorry, use `display: block;` not inline, that's my mistake.

Comment: Awesome! :D Thanks so much! Such a help, you have no idea!